# Navigate with routes (laravel blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes, navigation

Hi there so I am trying to construct a navbar that will change the information being displayed.

**NOTE using laravel 4**

The idea is to have one page where you enter information into a form and then another where you can then edit that form data but i cant get the bloody thing to navigate.

My directory is set up as such

```html
- app
-- views
--- layouts
------- default.blade.php
--- pages
------- home.blade.php
------- edit.blade.php
--- includes
------- head.blade.php
------- header.blade.php
------- footer.blade.php
```

And I would like to use something similar to this to navigate

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a id="logo" href="/">ABC123</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#"></a>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently my routes.php file looks like this

```html
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('pages.home');
});

Route::get('edit', function()
{
return View::make('pages.edit');
});
```

and here is my default.blade.php template that I want to use for both

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    @include('includes.head')
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <header class="row">
        @include('includes.header')
    </header>

    <div id="main" class="row">

            @yield('content')

    </div>

    <footer class="row">
        @include('includes.footer')
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help

Have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What [you need is the `url()` helper:](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls)

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}"></a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url('/edit') }}">Edit</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: HI there I used your code and the edit page works but then I navigate back to the home page I get an SSL Connection error "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"  I also removed the extra </a> that was there (*woops*)